# What's the best FREE collaborative platform for 2/3 programmers?

Tags: svn, collaboration

first of all I searched for similar question, there are many, but does't fit my requirements or are outdated (for example [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) seems to not be free anymore)

We are two developers that would like to work on some common small projects during our free time.

Our mainly need is to **have a SVN repository that allows possibly to have more than 1 project and 50 MB of storage at least**. It should be good have a minimal bug tracking tool or project management tool.

We are probably going to release our work open source, but we have not decided yet how. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: I am asking for SVN support because we develop on Windows guest and we like a lot how TortoiseSVN integrates into Win OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you still don't know if you want to go opensource with your projects you can try [beanstalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com) but you will have only one repo, but with 100MB.

Or you could also give a look at [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans) , only one repo but some more space.

Else, there are enough shared repos out there.

Comment: due to the fact that still we don't know if release our project open source immediately beanstalk look like the most interesting solution to start, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using git and the related [github](http://www.github.com) over SVN and it's related hosts. My basis being if a scm is not distributed it's not worth using.

Comment: And collab with git is so so much easier when complex conflicts arise.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/)?

I have created an account on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) for collaborative development with a couple of my friends. Their free plan gives you:

- 150MB storage
- 1 private repository
- unlimited public repositories
- issue tracker
- wiki

I also develop on Windows, so I have installed [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home) to provide similar Windows integration to what TortoiseSVN provides for Subversion.

As I am using Eclipse for some of my development, so I have also installed this plugin [Mercurial Eclipse](http://www.vectrace.com/mercurialeclipse/)

I can definitely recomend this setup for your situation, as I think distributed SCM is a better fit for this type of development.

Comment: This is good, I should know as I use the repository he's setup.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of open source hosting sites which offer svn, for example:

http://sourceforge.net/

http://code.google.com/projecthosting/

Answer (score 2):

I found to be [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and a own Subversion Repository to be a viable and low priced option.

i.e. in Google Code, your project has to be open source from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best, but it has free plan: [XP-Dev.com](http://www.xp-dev.com/)

- 500Mb SVN, can import existing repositories
- some sort of bug/issue/task tracking
- wiki, blog, forum
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net)? You have a free plan with unlimited private projects (Subversion and Git). It is a clone of GoogleCode with more things and it is also available as GPL software.